# The Events Calendar featured image as body background?

Tags: plugin-development, the-events-calendar

```
<?php if (has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) ):
$thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'full' ); 
elseif (tribe_event_featured_image( $event_id = get_the_ID())): $thumb = get_attachment_image_src(tribe_event_featured_image( $event_id), 'large' ); 
else: $thumb = array(get_template_directory_uri().'/images/background.jpg'); endif;?> <body <?php body_class(); ?> style="background-image: url('<?php echo $thumb['0'];?>') no-repeat fixed">
```

Hello Sir Experts,

Please help, i am using "The Events Calendar" plugin, and i want to use event featured image as body backgound. Please check code! and it's demo event page: http://rankonone.com/dev/downtown/event/the-lion-king/

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 

$id = get_the_ID();
if (has_post_thumbnail( $id ) ):
    $thumb = get_the_post_thumbnail_url($id, 'full'); 
elseif (tribe_event_featured_image( $id)): 
    $thumb = tribe_event_featured_image( $event_id, 'large', false, false ); 
else: 
    $thumb = get_template_directory_uri().'/images/background.jpg'; endif;?>
<body <?php body_class(); ?> style="background-image: url('<?php echo $thumb;?>'); background-size: cover;">
?>
```

Also you don't actually need the `elseif` statement, `tribe_event_featured_image` is a wrapper for the post thumbnail image with some added wrapping html.

Comment: Thanks for reply, But that's not working, please check SS: http://nimb.ws/TOqHQ6

Comment: I didn't check your CSS.  the image itself is pulling in fine with that.  I've edited the answer to fix CSS.